# Creating ARIMA model with a minimum value of forecast error in R

Tags: r, algorithm, loops, forecasting, arima

I use  `auto.arima()` function to build the ARIMA model and then calculate the forecast accuracy:

```
library(fpp2)

data("AirPassengers")

train <- window(AirPassengers, end = c(1959, 12))
test <- window(AirPassengers, start = 1960)

ARIMA <- auto.arima(train, lambda = 0, biasadj = TRUE)
ARIMAf <- forecast(ARIMA, h = 12)

accuracy(ARIMAf, test)
                     ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
Training set   0.579486  9.907267  7.483159  0.1187348 2.880429 0.2457523 0.01227544        NA
Test set     -16.986385 23.931703 18.527682 -3.9334909 4.182395 0.6084625 0.04802038 0.5336134
```

The `auto.arima()` function minimizes the value of `AIC`, `AICc` or `BIC`, but I would like to build an ARIMA model that has a minimum value such as `RMSE` on a test set. 
For example, by developing a set of ARIMA models with different values of parameters in order to find a model with a minimum RMSE on test set. 
Please help me understand how I can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ARIMA model is built on training data, and normally uses a least squares method to maximize its fit to the training data. It uses AIC or similar to decide between candidate models to prevent over-fitting.

Minimising the RMSE between the model and the test data depends on two things: the model, and the test data. You can't ask the model itself to reduce the RMSE unless the model also knows the test data. But the whole point of a predictive model is that you want to ask what the future value of a variable will be, so of course you can't include this in the model.

When you think about it, what you are asking is "how do I make my model look into the future?"

That's not to say you can't get a lower RMSE on your test data by altering the parameters of `arima.auto`, but you can only do this by comparing the output to the `test` data.

If you want to examine different parameters and see which model best fits the test data, you can automate multiple model fits like this:

```r
test_seasons <- function(train, test)
{
  seasonal = c("seas", "ocsb", "hegy", "ch")
  RMSE <- 1000
  for(i in 1:3)
  {
    latest_model <- auto.arima(train, lambda = 0,  biasadj = TRUE, seasonal.test = seasonal[i])
    latest_RMSE <- accuracy(forecast(latest_model, h = 12), test)[2, 2]
    if(latest_RMSE < RMSE)
    {
      RMSE <- latest_RMSE
      output <- latest_model
      best_season <- seasonal[i]
    }
  }
  cat("The optimal seasonal.test parameter was \"", best_season, "\" (RMSE ",
      RMSE, ")", sep = "")
}
```

So you can do

```
test_seasons(train, test)
# The optimal seasonal.test parameter was "seas" (RMSE 18.78836)
```

However, this kind of method will be very slow if you want to home in on optimal numerical parameters.

From a statistical perspective, I would also be cautious about selecting a model to use based on how well it predicts a single year. If you have an extra year worth of data, the best way to use it is to include it in your model, not to manually adjust parameters.

Comment: I would like to get the minimum RMSE by implementing an algorithm to automatically create several models with different parameters and then determine the model with the lowest RMSE on test set